# Python: storing and using information created in a function

Tags: python

I just began with Python and am having a little difficulty with storing the result of a function in a variable.

**I have a small script that does the following:**

- change to a directory and within that directory:
- create a new directory named to the moment it has been created (for example 2016200420161636)

**what i want it to do additionally:**

- create a file within that newly created directory

I would think to be able to have the file created in the newly created directory I need to store the directory name ( 2016200420161636) and return the value to a part of the script that creates the file (so it knows where to write the file to).

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Please try it on your own, and if it fails post your code, the error you are getting, and what you want it to do differently

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to just save the value before you create the directory?
something like

```
timestamp = time.clock()
if not os.path.exists(timestamp)
    os.makedirs(timestamp)
```

now timestamp has the value stored and you can use as needed